# Elasticsearch nodejs - No index found

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, heroku

I am using npm elasticsearch with bonsai on heroku and keep getting this error below:

```
    statusCode: 404,
  response: `{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index [question] and [action.auto_create_index] ([*logstash*,*requests*,*events*,*.kibana*,*kibana-int*,*filebeat*,.watches,.triggered_watches,.watcher-history-*]) doesn't match","index_uuid":"_na_","index":"question"}],"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index [question] and [action.auto_create_index] ([*logstash*,*requests*,*events*,*.kibana*,*kibana-int*,*filebeat*,.watches,.triggered_watches,.watcher-history-*]) doesn't match","index_uuid":"_na_","index":"question"},"status":404}`,
```

This is the code I am using, and there is currently no documents.

```
client.index({
                    index: 'question',
                    id: question_id,
                    type: 'questions',
                    body: {
                        "title": title,
                        "tags": tags
                    }
                }, function(err, resp, status) {
```

My hypothesis is that the index is not being created if it does not exist yet, but I thought it is automatically created by default?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

it's because of this part of the error;

> `no such index [question] and [action.auto_create_index] ([*logstash*,*requests*,*events*,*.kibana*,*kibana-int*,*filebeat*,.watches,.triggered_watches,.watcher-history-*]) doesn't match`

it's telling you that your index name doesn't match the allowed set of index pattern names that can be autocreated. take a look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-creation for more information on that

Comment: Thank you for the response, but not sure I understand what is wrong with the index pattern, because this worked with my AWS elasticsearch db but when trying it with heroku bonsai I started getting this error... can you elaborate?

Comment: I don't know how the bonsai service works, but you need to change that setting I linked to